# setUp/tearDown fixtures when unit testing in Laravel

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, phpunit, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to write a unit test that checks attribute method that uses `base_path()` helper, however, I'm getting an exception: `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Container\Container::basePath()`.

The full stacktrace is below:

```
\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php:179
\app\Message.php:47
\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasAttributes.php:432
\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasAttributes.php:333
\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasAttributes.php:306
\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php:1279
\tests\Unit\MessageTest.php:59
```

I've tracked it down to using `setUp` and `tearDown` fixtures - even if I've got:

```
public function setUp()
{
    //$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = dirname(__FILE__) . "/../..";
}

public function tearDown()
{
    //unset($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
}
```

I'm getting the abovementioned error. If I remove the fixtures entirely, the error goes away.

After I've replaced the given methods with `setUpBeforeClass` and `tearDownAfterClass` the error goes away, but I'd like to know what is causing it.

As far as I'm aware of this is vanilla Laravel 5.4 installation (5.4.36 exactly), but it has additional libraries installed (and I'm not really able to say what libraries). I've not setup the `phpunit.xml` file, but to be fair I'd not know what to look for.

I've tested it with fresh installation of Laravel (same version) and it does happen straight out of the box (with untouched phpunit.xml file); on version 5.5 it doesn't.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try calling the parent class setUp and tearDown methods inside your own.

Like so:

```
public function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();
    //$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = dirname(__FILE__) . "/../..";
}

public function tearDown()
{
    parent::tearDown();
    //unset($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
}
```

Comment: If you follow the inheritance for your test class you will end up in 
Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase.

Comment: This class has its own setUp and tearDown methods that actually set up Laravel in every test. So, when you do not call parent::setUp() in your test class this code is never run and there is no Laravel App and you get errors.

If you do not have your own setUp/tearDown methods the parent class version of setUp/tearDown will be automatically run by PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are calling the parent setUp() and tearDown() first before you continue down. See code down here

```
public function setUp()
{
    parent::setUp();
    //$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = dirname(__FILE__) . "/../..";
}

public function tearDown()
{
    parent::tearDown();
    //unset($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
}
```